# How to get AJAX to show a success function and allow the page to update database results

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have the following code that I cannot figure out how to allow my AJAX call to send to my PHP file and then allow my page to show the changes on the page without submitting the form. The reason I need the page to not reload is to allow the success message to display.

What I am trying to do is approve a user and once they have been approved their name will show up in a different section of the page and then I want the success message to display after the changes have been made.

As of now everything works in my database and the `status` changes. Also the success message shows up where it is supposed to, but the user's name does not move until I reload the page.

How can I get all of this to work without reloading the page?

```
if( $numrows ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            if($row['status'] == "Pending"){

                $pending_id        = $row['id'];
                $pending_user_id   = $row['user_id'];
                $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
                $pending_username  = $row['username'];
                $pending_email  = $row['email'];
?>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="status">
             <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id'/>
<?php
        if ($pending_firstname == true) {
            echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . 
                "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>"
?>


            <button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Approve</button>
            <button class="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Deny</button>
        </form>
```

AJAX

```
 $('.approve').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: $(this).val(), //id
                status: 'Approved' //status
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $("#success").fadeIn();
                $("#success").show();
                $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
                $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
            },
            //type: 'POST'
        });
        return false;
    });
```

UPDATE TO SHOW OUTPUTTED DATA

```
<h2>Approved User Requests</h2><br>
    <div id="success" style="color: red;"></div><br>
$run2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$runUsers2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($run2);

    if( $numrows2 ) {
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2)){
            if($row2['status'] == "Approved"){
            //var_dump ($row2);

                $approved_id        = $row2['user_id'];
                $approved_firstname = $row2['firstname'];
                $approved_lastname  = $row2['lastname'];
                $approved_username  = $row2['username'];
                $approved_email  = $row2['email'];

    if ($approved_firstname == true) {
        echo "Name - ". $approved_firstname . " " . $approved_lastname . "</br>" . 
            "Username - ". $approved_username . "</br></br>"
```

Comment: Does anything is called within the `success` callback? Did you try to simply add a console.log to it and see if thats working?

Comment: The only thing that is displayed is this ` $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');`, which is what I want it to say, but if there is another way to do it, than I will. Not sure what you mean by adding a console.log to it. Everything is working PHP wise and the AJAX is sending through, I just want the name to go to where it was changed to without having to reload the page and still show my message.

Comment: You make it very difficult by mixing all languages. Why not a html page, coupled with jQuery to AJAX request and after success you can 'manipulate' the dom with new data. Simple, isn't it?

Comment: @HenriS. I'm not quite too sure what you mean. I work primarily with PHP, and only use javascript for calls like this.

Comment: Whats inside `data` (in the `success` callback). Do you send anything back to the Frontend from your PHP?

Comment: In other words, whatever part of the page you want to be refreshable via ajax...make that a separate PHP page, give the main PHP page a div placeholder. Call that distinct php page with Ajax, and put the output in the div.

Comment: @paskl No, I don't send anything back. It is just an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @developerwjk How can I wrap all of my main PHP in a placeholder and allow it to still show? I am still outputting data all of the time with existing Approved and Denied users.

Comment: Well then, in the `success` callback update the information somewhere on the page. Eg. if its a list, add a new <li> to it with the users accountname. Its just javascript now.

Comment: Theres a term in the technology world, `MVC`, you should look that up @Paul

Comment: I updated my question to show how I output the data

Comment: $('#success').html(data);

Comment: @Medda86 What would that do?

Comment: Nothing as you probably dont have anything in your `data` variable (because you are not sending anything back to your frontend from your PHP.

In you success callback you know that PHP didnt throw any errors (if you coded it like that). So next step here is: do whatever you what with the data you currently have in your `DOM`. Eg. take the username (from a form) and place it somewhere. Thats totally just plain javascript stuff, I dont see the struggle here.

Comment: @paskl My struggle is I do not know much about Javascript as I write mostly in php. Am I able to echo out a message in my php and display that instead and allow my output to change?

Comment: No, if you echo anything out in your ajax php file it doesnt show up in the frontend. It just shows up in the ajax call (you can check that by taking a look in your developers toolbar of your browser, its called `XHR` request).
I cannot make it anymore clear, I am sorry. Your browser is executing the `success` callback when needed. And if its executed you may simply do anything to your `DOM` object. Like changing the background color to black or anything. We cannot tell you how its done in js as you simply dont give enough information.

Comment: It comes back as an xhr type in the network tab of the console. What information do you need? I'm not trying to un-include anything you need, just not sure what to put.

Comment: what you can do is on initial run of the main php, in your div do an include to the php you will later call via ajax to update it.

Comment: @developerwjk This will allow the user's name to go from my Pending section to the Approved section after I hit the 'Approve' button?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same page you call from your ajax query and for the message success ?

Comment: I make my AJAX call and have ` $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');` on the same page. Will this work if I echo out something on my php page to show up after the db has been updated?

Comment: You can't do it without reload the page. Maybe with websocket ? Or put your php verification code in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use json in your php file, then you can check for any values you add in the callback like this:

userRequest_approve.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '[{"success":1,"username","theusername"}]';
?>
```

script.js

```
$('.approve').click(function(){
    $.post('userRequest_approve.php',$('#status').serialize(),function(data){
        alert(data[0].success+' username='+data[0].username);
    },'json');

    return false;
});
```